# "library: failed" Error in Android Studio Sync Tab

Tags: android-studio

I'm encountering a "library: failed" error in the Sync tab during the Build process in Android Studio. There's no additional information provided with the error. Has anyone seen this before or have any suggestions on how to fix it?

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I just found the problem: In Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle I found that gradle-wrapper.properties does not exist for project "library"